# Use Padding and Margin (besides when Docking)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I put a Control (with `DockStyle.None`) on a Panel - it will be put in its `Location`, ignoring its own `Margin` and the Panel's `Padding`. Is there a way to tell it to go according to the Padding/Margin ? Or am I missing something obvious here?

What I'm trying to do is put Controls on a Panel and have them automatically have the same distance from the Panel's margins. And be able to change all of their Locations by a simple change to the Panel in the Designer.

Comment: IMO the only option is to extend the Panel control and intercept control addition and removal. A custom property for the location, padding, etc. will fire a change in the layout in design mode.

Comment: @pasty Thanks. Was hoping I was missing some simple Property that does that. If that's not the case - I'll just set them manually. But thanks again.

Comment: And have you thought about just puting one panel into another (maybe the second could be a FlowLayoutPanel - top to bottom) and all your components go into the inner panel, so if you resize the inner panel, all components are resized at once and the distance from border to border is the padding you want? This way no custom extension would be needed.